# Import Bootstrap 4 into Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, npm, bootstrap-4, laravel-6

I'm a Laravel newbie, and I was trying to import Bootstrap 4 automatically with `npm install` and `npm run dev` (after setting Bootstrap with its proper version into package.json) just as I saw in some Laravel classes I'm watching.

The problem is that after I use both commands, app.css is empty. Here's what I did this far.

1. composer create-project --prefer-dist "laravel/laravel" cadastro
2. Configuring package.json ("bootstrap": "^4.3.1")
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run dev`

Is there something wrong with my steps? My Laravel version is 6.5.2.

Comment: Here is an example with laravel mix to import jquery-ui, should be the same but with bootstrap por any js library https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/jquery-ui

Answer (score 2):

You should run

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

commands in your console to have some initial JS file with Bootstrap setup. Otherwise if `resources/js/app.js` file is empty, importing like this won't be enough.

You should read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/frontend#introduction) about this.